# Click on a element by javafx executeScript() is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, javafx, onclicklistener

Please tell me a solution that how to click on a  tag by javafx javascript which contains a onclick() function call.

My Javafx code for executing the JavaScript is as follows:

```
    webEngine.executeScript(
             "vv = setInterval(function(){"
            +"  var size="+newsize+";"
            +"  var p=document.getElementById('pdp_sizes');" 
            +"  var q=p.getElementsByTagName('li');"
            +"  for(var i=0;i<q.length;i++){"
            +"      var r=q[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];"    
            +"      if(r.innerHTML.trim()==size){"
            +"          r.className = 'available' + ' selected';"
            +"          r.click();"
            +"          product_form.submit();"
            +"          break;"
            +"      }"
            +"  }"
            +"  var s=document.getElementById('addToCartLink');"
            +"  s.click();"                                                        
            +"},"+delayInterval+");"                
        );
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="pdp_sizes">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="size_10_99583402" class="available" onclick="cmConversionEventSizeSelection(this);">13.0</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="addToCartLink" onmouseout="hideBubble()" onclick="showBubble(this)" href="javascript:addToCart()">
      <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </a>
```

My javafx code not working for both r.click(); and s.click(); but all other lines are working properly.